# TextArea Validation is not Working properly

Tags: angular, validation

I have a Modell driven Form in Angular which contains the following input field (among other input fields that do work properly (`input`):

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" type="text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="7" formControlname="message"></textarea>
      <small [hidden]="contactForm.controls['message'].valid || (contactForm.controls['subject'].untouched && !submitted)">
        Please enter a Message
      </small>
 </div>
```

In the component I did define some validation using:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.contactForm = new FormGroup({
        message: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });
}
```

But the message does never get Valid (The HTML does allways show `Please enter a Message`)

While the following Unit Tests do work as expected:

```js
it('message control should not be valid without input', () => {
  const messageControl: AbstractControl = component.contactForm.controls['message'];

  messageControl.setValue('');
  expect(messageControl.valid).toBe(false);
});

it('message control should be valid with any input', () => {
   const messageControl: AbstractControl = component.contactForm.controls['message'];

   messageControl.setValue('Some Message');
   expect(messageControl.valid).toBe(true);
});
```

Gave the expected results. Why is the Validation not working properly when I do input a Value manually?

Comment: `formControlname` --> `formControlName` was the problem :/

Answer (score 2):

Bind your form inside a formgroup first

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="contactForm">
<textarea class="form-control" type="text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="7" formControlname="message"></textarea>
<small [hidden]="contactForm.controls['message'].valid || (contactForm.controls['subject'].untouched && !submitted)">
        Please enter a Message
</small>
```

Comment: I do have it like that, the form has other fields that work properly. Sorry for not being clear enough i will add some info to the question.